# Learning Quartz

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-2d

What's a good book for learning Quartz in Objective-C? I thought about buying this book: [Quartz 2D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336631) however, a reviewer said it's written mainly in C (I only know ObjC). So does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Quartz *is* a C API, so you need to learn C. It's not a hard-core C with tons of pointer arithmetic etc., so you should just try!

Comment: Objective C is a superset of C; if you know Objective C, you *already* know C.

Comment: Or actually - if you don’t know C you don’t know Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz uses a C API, just like many of Apple's frameworks.  So it stands to reason that any book on Quartz is going to have a lot of C code.  It is also a good idea to get very comfortable with C code since it is a subset of Objective C, and you'll have to frequently work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1) from Apple? It explains things quite in detail.

Comment: While it is a good read. I feel a book would offer more context to each function. This is my first time doing graphics, so I have no foundation.

Comment: Im afraid that how many books are going to be more detail than this guide. However, if this is your first lesson in graphics(that is you don't understand what does translation, rotation means, how to obtain transformation matrix etc.) then definitely this is not right book. In that case you should start with a graphics text book.